# DOM shows that image has loaded, but page does not show image

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm loading an image after a submit from a form, here is my code:

```
$('#new_student').submit(function(event) {
    var spinner = '<%= image_tag("admin/loading.gif") %>';
    $('#register_student').replaceWith(spinner);
});
```

This is part of the asset pipeline on Rails 3.2. The button is properly replaced with the image, and the DOM correctly shows the path to the image, but the page only shows the missing image symbol. Any ideas on why this would happen?

**EDIT**

When I inspect the button, it properly replaces and I can click on the image path and view the image, so obviously the path is correct. The problem is, it does not show on the page itself.

Comment: Because the image is, in fact, missing?

Comment: try image_tag("loading.gif")

Comment: The image tag is in a folder called admin, that's why the path is admin/loading.gif. I can move the image to the root and the same thing happens. I can click on the image when it is replaced when I inspect it and it is the correct image, but it does not show on the page.

Comment: Is register_student set to be visible?

Comment: @Fred yes, the #register_student is just the submit button

Comment: You replace the button with an img element; I did the replacement by hand and had the broken image display for a few seconds before the animated gif loaded. Perhaps the image hasn't loaded and therefore can't display before the page reloads? I might try loading the image on the page but make it not visible, then use replaceWith() to replace the button with the (fully loaded) img element. Worth a shot.

Comment: @Fred you should post that as an answer because it worked, that way I can give you mad props!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is clicked and the button element is replaced with an image, the page shows the 'missing image' symbol until the image fully loads. Instead of loading the image after the button is clicked, make it a non-visible element elsewhere on the page. Now when the button is clicked, the image is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe set the z-index wrong somewhere, so the image is invisible??

Comment: No, I can see the image path (I'm using chrome, so it just displayed as the mountain picture)

Comment: Better yet, here's it in action (just click register, no need to fill anything out): https://www.worldbibleschool.org/register